# About official release version of "Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview)" of Visual Studio

Tags: release, visual-studio-cordova

Could anyone give me a rough period about when the Official release version of "Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview)" of Visual Studio will be?

I know it's CTP1 at the moment.

Thanks alot.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculating about future release dates.

Answer (score 1):

We are super excited about these new features in Visual Studio and are hoping to release updates as soon as possible. But only once they're completely ready for primetime!

Please monitor our [page](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398477) for details and updates.

-Priyank, Visual Studio Client Tools Team